# Which is the best way to filter in a select input?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I get this response from the API:

```
[
    {
        "id": 6,
        "nombre": "Pechuga de pollo",
        "categoria": "Pollo",
        "existencia": 100
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "nombre": "Pierna de pavo",
        "categoria": "Pollo",
        "existencia": 100
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "nombre": "Lonja de pescado",
        "categoria": "Pescado",
        "existencia": 200
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "nombre": "Coca Cola",
        "categoria": "Bebida",
        "existencia": 200
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "nombre": "Jugo de naranja",
        "categoria": "Bebida",
        "existencia": 200
    }
]
```

So I need to filter these json by the value "categoria", then I'll fill three differents select inputon my template.

I tried with the filter() method but I guess I'm doing wrong:

```
///This is the function that filter needs on the argument:

filtradoBebida(bebida){
             bebida.categoria == "Bebida"
    },

///This is the function where I apply the filter method:

filtrarProductos(){
       this.bebidas = productosLista.filter(filtradoBebida)
 }
```

I want to fill a select with the json where the value categoria == "Bebida", other select input with the json where the value == "Pollo".

"bebidas" is an array from my data
""productosLista" is an array that recieves the response from the API.

Do you know another way to fill a select in vuejs by filtering a value of the json?

Comment: You are missing the return statement in `filtradoBebida`.

Comment: Also, it looks like it should be `this.filtradoBebida` to call that method.

Comment: We'll need more context, I don't know what `filtradoBebida` is but it looks like a property of an object, if that is the case, you'll have to use `productosLista.filter(this.filtradoBebida)`

Answer (score 0):

You don't use `filter` correctly.

What i suggest is to use an [ES6 arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) :

```js
///This is the function where I apply the filter method:

filtrarProductos () {
       this.bebidas = productosLista.filter(x => x.categoria === "Bebida")
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties). Here's the basic outline of a component that can filter its `items`:

```
<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in filteredItems" :key="item.id">{{ item.text }}</li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      // Set this via an API call
      // Here we assume an item has: id, text, category
      items: [],
      // Use this as the v-model for a select
      // Here we assume '' is "no selection"
      category: '',
    };
  },
  computed: {
    filteredItems() {
      // Show all of the items if there is not category filter
      if (this.category === '') return this.items;
      return this.items.filter(item => item.category === this.category);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm little bit confused with the comma which comes after `filtradoBebida`.
Seems like it is a property in some object.
Thus `this` is needed to call it from inside this object.

Also to be a correct filter predicate it should return a Boolean value.
Yours returns `undefined` always.

So, try

```js
filtradoBebida(bebida){
             return bebida.categoria == "Bebida"
    },

///This is the function where I apply the filter method:

filtrarProductos(){
       this.bebidas = productosLista.filter(this.filtradoBebida)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use, `array.reduce` to create a categoryMap where each category key can hold a list of similar category products. Then use this filtered product list to populate your 3 select components like so:

```js
const productosLista = [{
    "id": 6,
    "nombre": "Pechuga de pollo",
    "categoria": "Pollo",
    "existencia": 100
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "nombre": "Pierna de pavo",
    "categoria": "Pollo",
    "existencia": 100
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "nombre": "Lonja de pescado",
    "categoria": "Pescado",
    "existencia": 200
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "nombre": "Coca Cola",
    "categoria": "Bebida",
    "existencia": 200
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "nombre": "Jugo de naranja",
    "categoria": "Bebida",
    "existencia": 200
  }
]

const categoryMap = productosLista.reduce((acc, dt) => {
  acc[dt.categoria] = acc[dt.categoria] ? [...acc[dt.categoria], dt] : [dt]
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(categoryMap);

for (category in categoryMap) {
  let sel = document.createElement('select');
  let categories = categoryMap[category];
  categories.forEach(category => {
    let option = document.createElement("option");
    option.setAttribute("value", category.nombre);
    option.text = category.nombre;
    sel.appendChild(option);
  });
  document.body.append(sel);
}
```