# Can I use variables in a filter method?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, filtering

Can I assign values to to variables and then use those variables in a js filter method?

I am trying to use local data assigned to two variables and then use those variables in my filter method.  I'm trying this as I want to filter an array using several different filters (key and value, ex. age: 5).  I have a player array and you can select one or more things to filter your players by.  As the user selects filters, they are saved in a filters[].  I want to iterate through the filters[] and apply each filter to an array of players.  The first filter needs to be used on the array with all of the players and then each following filter can be used on the filtered array (making it smaller each iteration).  My code only shows my initial first filter method.

```
applyFirstFilter() {
      let filterValue = this.filters[0];
      let filterKey = this.checkValue(filterValue);
      console.log("key: " + filterKey + ", filterValue: " + filterValue);

      //loop through filters[]
      // apply first filter to allPlayers and assign to displayPlayerArray
      this.displayedPlayerArray = this.allPlayersArray.filter(player => player.filterKey === filterValue);
      console.log("displayed array: " + this.displayedPlayerArray);

      // apply all remaining filters to displayPlayerArray

      },
```

The console shows that filterValue and filterKey have the values I expect them to have.  All of the research I've done displays fixed examples, such as:

```
var ages = [32, 33, 16, 40];

function checkAdult(age) {
  return age >= 18;
}

function myFunction() {
  this.localArray = ages.filter(checkAdult);
}
```

So far my filter method does not affect my array.  I'm really not sure this is actually doable. : / Any ideas?

Comment: console.log showing correct result?

Comment: @winterfive It's hard to answer this without more detail about your array and the filters. You can see a generic filter example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56550035/which-is-the-best-way-to-filter-in-a-select-input/56550216#56550216). I strongly recommend using computed properties for your filter results. You can even chain them w/o having to assign a value - see [this example](https://vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Simple-computed-properties-strongly-recommended).

Comment: Pretty surely you meant `player[filterKey]`.

Comment: @AdilLiaqat Yep. I said so in write up, "The console shows that filterValue and filterKey have the values I expect them to have." :)

Answer (score 2):

To answer your most basic question: yes, you can use variables in a filter. To take the age filtering example, you could make that use a variable instead of a fixed number:

```
var ages = [32, 33, 16, 40];

function checkAge(age, minAge) {
  return age >= minAge;
} 

function myFunction(minAge) {
  return ages.filter((age) => checkAge(age, minAge));
} 

myFunction(18); // returns [32, 33, 40];
myFunction(30); // returns [40]
```

Now, why your code isn't working is a little harder to figure out. To do so, we'd need to know more about the structure of `allPlayersArray` and `this.filters`

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem right:

```js
this.displayedPlayerArray = this.allPlayersArray.filter(player => player.filterKey === filterValue);
```

`player.filterKey` will be looking for a property with the name `filterKey`, it won't be using the variable `filterKey`.

I'm guessing you want something like this, using square brackets:

```js
this.displayedPlayerArray = this.allPlayersArray.filter(player => player[filterKey] === filterValue);
```

Beyond that I'd need example data to debug further.

Comment: @Idtcoop Thanks.  From your example, I would need minAge to become each value stored in my local daya (currentAge, currentGender, etc) and age would be the value from filters[].  I know it's unusual and I feel like I need to simplify this set up.

Comment: @skirtie I'll try the square brackets (I forgot I could use those too).  Thanks.  I'll also just rearchitecture things to just be more simple as my current set up seems (feels) wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the input everyone!  I know the initial post was confusing.  I tried to explain as best I could.  Getting better.  

“She turned me into a newt. ... But I got better...”